# Angular Multiple Page Data Retention Challenge

Tags: angular, api, retention

I got a specific question on an Angular Mobile Web where I will have several pages on a sequence for the user to type in the data, Let's say Page 1, Page 2, and Page 3. The user will navigate from page 1 to page 2 and page3, and eventually collects the data and submit it to the backend API.

My question is how can Angular preserver all the data on Page 1, Page 2, and Page 3 and eventually submit all the data to the backend API?

Also is there a session concept in Angular, like after 10 minutes inactive of the page, all the data is gone from the Angular page?

Comment: Better if you could make all of them in a single component.
Yes there is session storage, you can store the data in session storage and you can programmatically delete them with time constraint.

Comment: Thanks, you meant to say, I can still collect data from different Angular Pages, but as long as I can save all the the data from different pages into a single component, this data will be available when navigating from page to page, and submit all the data to DB/Backend API at the last step (Page 3)? If yes, can you show some code examples? also regarding the session storage, can you show me some coding examples?

Comment: I guess you are trying to set a register page or creation page or something like that.

You can use three divs to display three "pages" you mentioned, so that you can get all the data inside a single component. If you use any ui kit, make use of modals, they are absolutely helpful. At the end, you can pass the whole data to backend.

sessionStorage.setItem('clickCounter', clicks); -> to set data
sessionStorage.getItem('clickCounter'); -> to get data

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions for preserving data in angular:

- **State management** (ngrx, ngxs, etc): these libraries are used for keeping a state in the data of your application. You can even make the state persistent by saving it to `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` However, if you don't know how state management libraries work, keep in mind that there is a learning curve. If you want to go this way start [here](https://ngrx.io/docs)
- **Data service**: You can create a service that keeps the data from each page and consume the data when you want to submit. You can see an example of this practice [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/)
- **Parent component**: You can use the `@Input` and `@Output` to pass data between child/parent components all the way to the top parent and keep the data there (*not as good as the previous ways*)

My suggestion would be to add a state management library and learn how it works, since it's knowledge that is going to benefit you in future projects also, and is an industry standard at this point.

About the second part of your question, you can create a kind of session manually by using rxjs and its operators (e.g. [timer](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/timer))